# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{1/n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

> Does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{1/n}}$ converge? converge in absolute value or conditionally?

It's easy to see that in absolute value the general term tends to $1$ so the series diverges in absolute value.

The term of the series doesn't tend to zero either so it's impossible to use the alternating series test. Can I conclude from the inability to use the alternating test that the series diverges?

Note: No integrals or Taylor's.

Comment: It would be a great thing to have the same series in the title and in the question body.

Comment: lol whoops, fixing that.

Comment: I doubt it since $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{1/n}}$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: Being unable to use the Alternating Series Test tells us nothing. Being unable to use it *because* the terms do not have limit $0$ tells us the series does not converge. But there is no need to drag in the irrelevant Alternating Series Test. Since the terms do not have limit $0$, the series does not converge.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I wanted to know for sure since it will probably come up more. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. "Terms don't go to $0$" is the simplest non-convergence test for series. It is often forgotten about, perhaps because terms do go to $0$ does not imply convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the general terme doesn't converge to zero it can't converge. Indeed, if $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n x_n$ converge, then $(S_{n})$ is a Cauchy Sequence and thus
$$|S_{n+1}-S_n|=|x_{n+1}|<\varepsilon$$
if $n\geq N$ for a certain $N\in\mathbb N$ and all $\varepsilon>0$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=0$. Then, if $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n\neq 0$, the series doesn't converge.

Comment: Just to make sure, in this case the limit of term in the sum doesn't exist since it's either 1 or -1 right?

Comment: You right, it doesn't exist, therefore it's not 0.

Answer (score 1):

The terms *must* converge to zero for the sum to converge.  That's true whether it is alternating or not.  Since you apparently know already that the terms do not converge to zero, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1\not=0$$ therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/n}} \text{does not exist}.$$